# How to give quota for linux users?

Tags: linux, quota, disk-space-utilization

I want to give quota for each user on my linux box, so that each one will get only specified amount of disk space.

Answer (score 3):

Ideally you will have /home as a separate partition. If you do, try this:
Find the filesystem for /home, for example:
`mount | grep "/home"`
`/dev/sda3 on /home type ext3 (rw,noatime,errors=remount-ro)`
`mount -o remount,quota /home`
`quotacheck /dev/sda3`
`edquota username`
Set the soft and hard quotas in there. This will only apply for the current boot, to make it survive a reboot edit /etc/fstab and add ",quota" to the end of the mount options for /dev/sda3 (in this example).

Answer (score 1):

Fredley tutorial is kinda out of date. This one is the one you need: [Quota Mini Howto](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Quota.html)

Basically you need to enable quotas on `/etc/fstab` and configure the quotas using the quota tools (`edquota`, mainly). Is also cool to configure `quotacheck` as a cron job.

Remember that quota is enabled per filesystem, so if you have 3 different partitions you have to enable and edit the quotas on each one of them. Just read the howto carefully and you will be set.

Answer (score 0):

Google is your friend

http://souptonuts.sourceforge.net/quota_tutorial.html